# Can Breadth-First Search be Implemented Recursively without Data Structures?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, recursion, graph-traversal

I'm in a data structures course, but our current unit discusses recursion and not data structures, and I need to implement breadth-first recursion for the purpose of finding the shortest path through a maze. Is there a way to do this just using the basic structure of recursive calls and base cases? Or will I need data structures such as queues or stacks to implement breadth-first recursion?

Comment: Note that if you use recursion you use a *stack*. I don't know that you can implement *any* graph traversal without an auxiliary data strcuture.

Comment: Essentially "YES"; see http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/fgl/haskell/old/fgl0103.pdf for the definition. Moreover, with a slight change, you get DFS ;)

Comment: See also: [Performing Breadth First Search recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549541/performing-breadth-first-search-recursively) on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 9):

You basically have two choices: "cheating" by embedding a queue in the nodes, and simulating BFS with higher complexity.

---

**Embedded-Queue Cheating**

If you look at virtually any description of BFS, e.g., [this one on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Pseudocode), then you can see that the algorithm adds attributes to nodes. E.g., the Wikipedia version adds to each node the attributes `distance` and `parent`.

So, even if you aren't allowed to use some clearly-cut external queue data structure, you can easily embed one using node attributes:

```
def BFS(G, root):
    for each node in G:
        n.distance = inf
        n.parent = None
        n.next = None

    root.distance = 0
    head = tail = root

    while head is not None:
         current = tail
         tail = tail.next

         for each node adjacent to current:
             if n.distance == inf:
                  n.distance = current.distance + 1
                  n.parent = parent
                  head.next = n
                  head = head.next
                  if tail is None:
                       tail = head
```

Note that the above code is iterative, but it's trivial to make it recursive.

---

**Higher-Complexity Simulation**

It's possible to run BFS recursively without any data structures, but with higher complexity. DFS, as opposed to BFS, uses a stack instead of a queue, and so it can be implemented recursively.

Suppose we modify DFS so that it takes a `max_depth` parameter:

```
 MaxDepthDFS(G, s, max_depth)
```

It should perform DFS until it reaches the first unvisited node at `max_depth` level, and returns whether it indeed found such a node. Then we could write the following variation of BFS:

```
 def BFS(G, s):

     depth = 0
     for i = 0, ..., |V|:
         if not DFS(G, s, depth)
             depth += 1
```

Again, note that the above code is iterative, but it's trivial to make it recursive.

---

Besides such (cheap) tricks, you cannot run BFS, as it uses a queue, and not a stack. Say, to the contrary, you have a recursive function

```
BFSVisit(G, s, current, more)
```

and consider the case where $s$ has $m$ neighbors. Then at the $m$th invocation, `more` needs to carry $\omega(1)$ information, and thus is already a data structure.

Comment: can you elaborate more on MaxDepthDFS ? why are we checking if not DFS (G, s, depth) ?